# Create Login for Heroku App

Tags: heroku, node.js, node-salesforce

Currently my Heroku app is completely based on the static settings passed in app.json file.

How to add login screen to the Heroku app? and,
Can this information be stored, when next time user loads the URL?

I got the SSO setup information from [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-salesforce-identity-sso-with-heroku) url. But, nothing says about login with username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a plugin that could meet the requirement. `passport` offers forcedotcom plug-in installation.

https://github.com/joshbirk/passport-forcedotcom

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to your Salesforce Admin homepage.
Click Administer > Manage Users > Profiles.
Click the Profile Name of the user profile to which you want to extend Heroku login.
Click the “Edit” button, scroll down to the Connected App Access, and select the Connected App you created in the previous page. (Repeat this step for any other user profiles that should be also be granted SSO login for Heroku.)
Scroll to the bottom of the page and click Save.